# Node: how to test multiple events generated by an async process

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, jestjs, mocha.js

I need to test an async [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v12.x/api/) library which periodically generates events (through [EventEmitter](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v12.x/api/events.html#events_class_eventemitter)) until done. Specifically I need to test data object passed to these events.
The following is an example using [mocha](https://mochajs.org/) + [chai](https://www.chaijs.com/):

```js
require('mocha');
const { expect } = require('chai');
const { AsyncLib } = require('async-lib');

describe('Test suite', () => {

  const onDataHandler = (data) => {
    expect(data.foo).to.exist;
    expect(data.bar).to.exist;
    expect(data.bar.length).to.be.greaterThan(0);
  };

  it('test 1', async () => {
    const asyncLib = new AsyncLib();

    asyncLib.on('event', onDataHandler); // This handler should be called/tested multiple times

    await asyncLib.start(); // Will generate several 'events' until done

    await asyncLib.close();
  });
});
```

The problem is that even in case of an `AssertionError`, mocha marks the test as passed and the program terminates with exit code 0 (instead of 1 as I expected).

The following uses `done` callback instead of async syntax, but the result is the same:

```js
require('mocha');
const { expect } = require('chai');
const { AsyncLib } = require('async-lib');

describe('Test suite', () => {

  const onDataHandler = (data) => {
    expect(data.foo).to.exist;
    expect(data.bar).to.exist;
    expect(data.bar.length).to.be.greaterThan(0);
  };

  it('test 1', (done) => {
    const asyncLib = new AsyncLib();

    asyncLib.on('event', onDataHandler);

    asyncLib.start()
      .then(asyncLib.close)
      .then(() => done());    
  });
});
```

I have also tried with a "pure" Node.js approach using the native [assert.ok](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v12.x/api/assert.html#assert_assert_ok_value_message) without any 3rd part library:

```js
const { strict: assert } = require('assert');
const { AsyncLib } = require('async-lib');

const test = async () => {
    const onDataHandler = (data) => {
      assert.ok(data.foo != null);
      assert.ok(data.bar != null);
      assert.ok(data.bar.length > 0);
    };

    asyncLib.on('event', onDataHandler);

    const asyncLib = new AsyncLib();

    await asyncLib.start();

    await asyncLib.close();
}

(async () => {
  await test();
})();
```

Even in this case, an `AssertionError` would make the program to terminate with exit code 0 instead of 1.

How can I properly test this code and make the tests correctly fail in case of an assertion error?

Answer (score 0):

There are some things that you need to fix to make it works:

1. Make your test async, because the test is going to execute the expects after a certain event is received meaning it's going to be asyncronous.
2. Your event handler in this case `onDataHandler` should receive the done callback because there is the way how you can indicate to mocha that the test was finished successful as long as the expects don't fail.

I wrote some code and tested it out and it works, you have to make some changes to adapt your async library though:

```
describe('Test suite', function () {

  const onDataHandler = (data, done) => {
    expect(data.foo).to.exist;
    expect(data.bar).to.exist;
    expect(data.bar.length).to.be.greaterThan(0);
    done();
  };

  it('test 1', async function (done) {
    eventEmitter.on('event', (data) => onDataHandler(data, done));

    setTimeout(() =>{
      eventEmitter.emit('event', {
      })
    }, 400)

  });

});
```

Comment: This will work only if the event handler is fired once, but in this case it needs to be fired several times. Also note that the test is already marked as async

Comment: Do you want to test how many times `onDataHandler` is called? what I understood by your question > How can I properly test this code and make the tests correctly fail in case of an assertion error? is that you want your test fail when the event handler is called, but do you want your test fail N times if the event handler is fired N times ?
For another hand, I wrote the point 1 just because in your second example you wrote a non-async test to test an async function, though with Jest (IDK mocha) you can test async code within a non-async function as long as the last function return a promise.